# repeat a line, splitting one field

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a tab delimited file in which in every line I have this:

```
K00001;K00004;K00008    0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
```

I would like to have one row with a unique code and the same sequence of numbers like this:

```
K00001 0    0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0    
K00004 0    0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0    
K00008 0    0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
```

Comment: Ilario, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

You can use awk to split the first column:

```
~$ awk '{split($1,a,";"); $1="";for (i in a){print a[i],$0}}' myfile
K00001  0 0 34 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 36 0 0 52 0 0 0 6 0
K00004  0 0 34 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 36 0 0 52 0 0 0 6 0
K00008  0 0 34 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 36 0 0 52 0 0 0 6 0
```

You split the first column on `;` (`split($1,a,";")`) and then you delete it, to print the whole (new) line (`$0`) for each item in the array.

---

As suggested in the comment, after the edit, we can see that tabs are used as separator. To use tab as Output Field Separator, you can use `OFS="\t"`, for instance in the `BEGIN` part of awk. Besides, an empty field is inserted with `$1=""`. So instead of printing `a[i]` then `$0`, it is better to set `$1` to `a[i]` and then print `$0`:

```
~$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,";"); for (i in a){$1=a[i];print}}' myfile
K00001  0       0       34      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       36      0       0       52      0       0       0       6       0
K00004  0       0       34      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       36      0       0       52      0       0       0       6       0
K00008  0       0       34      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       36      0       0       52      0       0       0       6       0
```

Comment: You'd better set `OFS="\t"` so the resulting file is of the same format as the input. This might be better: `for (i in a) {$1 = i; print}` -- that does not insert an empty field for the previous $1.

Comment: @glennjackman would still want to use `a[i]`, `for (i in a) {$1 = a[i]; print}`

Comment: @Jidder, completely right.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want. Basically, we put the first field (the keys) in `$k` and the rest of the fields in `$f` by splitting on `\t` and limiting the split to the first `2` fields. Then we split the keys on `;` and print each key along with the remaining fields on its own line.

```
perl -nle '($k, $f) = split "\t", $_, 2; print "$_\t$f" for split ";", $k'
```

`-n` loops over input. You can either pipe your file to perl or pass the name of the input file at the end of the command line. `-l` enables automatic line ending management.

Comment: I wonder if `($keys, $fields) = split /\t/, $_, 2` would be more efficient that a regex with captures.

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, you're probably right. i updated my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:];]*\);\([^[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3\
\2\3/;P;D'
```

Answer (score 2):

the awk file

```
 {
   split($1,A,";") ;
   for ( a in A )
    {
    printf "%s",A[a] ;
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "\t%s",$i ;
    printf "\n" ;
    }
  }
```

where

- `split($1,A,";")` put into A all the sub filed of $1
- `for ( a in A )` loop through value of A
- `printf "%s",A[a] ;` print the first value
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "\t%s",$i ;` print remaining value in command line
- `printf "\n" ;` the new  line

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl one-liner.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^([^;]+);([^;]+);(\S+)\s+(.*)/$1 $4\n$2 $4\n$3 $4/' file
K00001 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
K00004 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
K00008 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
```

Another sed one-liner.

```
$ sed 's/^\([^;]\+\);\([^;]\+\);\([^ ]\+\) \+\(.*\)/\1 \4\n\2 \4\n\3 \4/' file
K00001 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
K00004 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
K00008 0   0   34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   52  0   0   0   6   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Longer Perl version, that allows you to access the data per key and further process if required.
This does also not use capturing from regular expressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;

my %hash; 

while ( my $line = <> ){
    #splitting the line into two parts at the first TAB.
    my ($keys, $value) = split (/\t/ , $line, 2);

    #splits the set of keys at each semicolon
    my @key = split /;/, $keys;

    #@key is used in scalar context here to get the number of keys.
    #this is used to determine how many values we need to put into the hash
    @hash{@key} = ($value) x @key; 
}

for my $key (keys %hash){
    print "$hash{$key}\n"; 
}
```

Further reading:

- [Hash slices can replace loops](http://www.webquills.net/web-development/perl/perl-5-hash-slices-can-replace.html)
- [Perl documentation: perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Answer (score 0):

Slow day at work, so here's a `python` solution

```
python3 -c 'import sys
x = (l.partition("\t") for l in sys.stdin)
x = ((l[0].split(";"), l[1] + l[2]) for l in x)
for a in x:
  print(*a[0], sep=a[1], end=a[1])
' <file
```